# ASP.NET Web API Vs/AND/OR NODE API

Tags: node.js, asp.net-web-api

I have been working with .NET WEB APIs since long and have learnt NODE APIs a bit.
I love working with Javascript and/or C#.
If I look at .NET WEB API, I really can see that things are already developed and taken care by MICROSOFT. 
If I look at NODE APIs, I can (at this stage) understand things are working greatly and growing day by day and may be taken care greatly (but I don't know too much about it).

Now being a software developer(.NET), I can play with .NET WEB APIs as I want as I have pretty much experienced with it. .NET WEB API does almost every thing that I want.

Recently,I came across alasql.js(I think its APIs are written in NODE (not sure)). In order to create an excel , I just have to get the list of objects from .NET WEB API, throw it to client end, at client end I will use single line code and it will generate an excel. (So simple. Same thing is possible in C# .and NET WEB API)...

I know NODE is widely used. but at this stage it seems a different platform to me. I'd like to go on with NODE.

I know its amazing if I could run javascript code onto server with NODE.

I know both are great.

But I'm confused with How and When to use them together, individually?